# Is the Server SSL certificates are bound to port?

Tags: security, https, websocket

I have a scenario where Https is running in 443 and Secure webSocket Server running in other port and both service we are using same selfsigned certifcate.

An we first access the page over https and we install the certificate and page contains js to connect to webSocket securely.

When we try to connect to websocket , its failing , but if we access the WSS url in the browser address bar and add the certficate, the from the web page we are able to connect to webSocket server.

How to overcome this as we want to install the certificate once and same can be used to WSS?

Thanks in advance

Pradeep

Comment: An SSL certificate is not bound to a port; however, when running with HTTPS, it is bound to the declared hostname. Does the server have several hostnames?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.no it has only one hostname and for your reference i using chrome

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yes we tested its not bound to port. the above scenario is working fine